# Pass Record variable to .NET library

Tags: dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013

Is there a way to pass variable of Record (or RecordRef) type as a parameter to method of .NET object?

Comment: But how do you want it to appear on .NET side — as an object with fields as properties?

Comment: @sergeyol yes as datatable or something

Comment: I don't think this would be possible... Though, it'd be nice if it was automatically (and well) cast just like Stream/InStream/OutStream, etc.

Comment: Have a chat with Vjeko (http://vjeko.com/) - he is the guy who knows the most about .NET + NAV

Answer (score 1):

In theory it is not possible pass like datatable or something else. What you can do is to create a **public class in .NET** that is visible in **NAV**, complete the data of that class and pass the **.NET class** as a parameter with the data in the NAV table.

For example **table 18 (Customer)** you can create a *.NET class with the same structure*, call this class in NAV code, complete the data in NAV and then pass this class with the same fields data as table 18 to .NET

If you need pass a parameter multiples registers of the same table create a **Array** of this .NET class perform a loop, assing the values and pass one by one to **.NET**

I made a code similar to the one I told you about and it works correctly.